# Why this code doesn't allow me to enter a new input?

Tags: java, do-while

This is the code:

```
public class Pr3 
{
  public Pr3 ()
  {
    String x = "";
    String Line = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    do 
    {
        System.out.println ("Please enter your sentence");
        String NewLine = sc.nextLine();
        Line = Line + " " + NewLine;
        System.out.println ("Your new Line is: " + Line); 
        System.out.println ("Do you want to enter a new sentence? Enter Y for yes and N for no");
        x = sc.next();
    } while (!"N".equals(x) && "Y".equals(x));
    exit(0);
   }
 }
```

And this is the output:

- Please enter your sentence
- Hagar
- Your new Line is:  Hagar
- Do you want to enter a new sentence? Enter Y for yes and N for no
- Y
- Please enter your sentence
- Your new Line is:  Hagar
- Do you want to enter a new sentence? Enter Y for yes and N for no

Comment: Ah sorry, It's because I am working on two projects now xD

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
x = sc.next();
```

to

```
x = sc.nextLine();
```

in order to consume the end of line characters.

Beside that,

```
Line = Line + " " + NewLine;
```

will concatenate the new line to all the previous lines. I'm not sure that's what you want (based on your printing of `System.out.println ("Your new Line is: " + Line);`).

One last thing :

```
while (!"N".equals(x) && "Y".equals(x));
```

is redundant. If `x` is equal to `"Y"`, it's not equal to `"N"`, so it's enough to write :

```
while ("Y".equals(x));
```

Comment: It's working now, thanks :)